# command gsutil not found by the playbook but exists on system

Tags: linux, ansible, gsutil

i am trying to install gsutil on some machine via this playbook :

```
     become: yes
     snap:
       name: google-cloud-sdk
       classic: yes
       state: present

   - name: get the gsutil version
     shell: "gsutil --version"
```

it returns :

```
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/bin/sh: 1: gsutil: not found"
    ], 
    "stdout": "",
```

but when i connect to the machine via ssh i can find the command and i get :

```
gsutil version: 5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the `PATH` environment variable is not set correctly on the script that tries to run `gsutil`.

To check if that is the case, run `which gsutil` in your ssh terminal to find the location of the `gsutil` program, and then, in your script, run the command using its absolute path.

If that works, you could either:

1. Fix your environment variable (the recommended solution, but could be hard to do)
2. Use it this way, if that's the only problem you face.